# A Simple return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello everyone i am new to rails just wanted to ask What this line will return

```
    @client = Client.find(params[:contact_info][:client_id])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will find a `record` in `client` table having `id` equal to `params[:contact_info][:client_id]` and assign the column value to respective `attributes` in `Client module new object` and then it is `referenced` to `@client`

Comment: or it will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception if a Client  with specified id does not exist.